# Customize ContentAlpha in Jetpack Compose like a theme

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

My Customer has very strict design guidelines, e.g. for alpha:
Text should have no alpha.

However, I can't seem to customize MaterialDesign´s alpha **in a theme like way**.

Sure, I can customize each and every component, but this is tedious:
`Modifier.alpha(1.0f)`

Sure, I can wrap my whole app in an alpha-Provider, but most material-components overwrite it, e.g. `AppBar`, so this doesn't work as expected either.

```
// my wrapper:
CompositionLocalProvider(LocalContentAlpha provides 1.0f) { /* my ui */ }

// will be overwritten by 
@Composable
private fun AppBar(...) {
    Surface(...) {
        CompositionLocalProvider(LocalContentAlpha provides ContentAlpha.medium) {
            Row(..., content)
        }
    }
}
```

So I guess what I should be doing is providing a custom `ContentAlpha`, since it is used in nearly every material component, but I don't know how to. Do you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to me like you don't really need material design and want to just go custom theme. It's fine, really, I'm currently working on production app that went in that direction and it's completely workable.

We are still wrapping our content with `MaterialTheme` to make SOME of material components available, but the material dependency is internal to base ui module. So if we want to use any material component in UI code (in feature for example) - we have to create our wrapper for it. This way we are using only our code in UI without loosing some of material components. And if material design will change in a way we cannot accept it - we can just reimplement the thin wrapper to something 100% custom (like we did with `Button` and text fields).

You can override any part of material component within those thin wrappers using `Modifier.alpha(1.0f)`. You are doing it once and then forget about that :)

Comment: This answer solves my problem, however, it seems like a lot of work. Dang, even my `Text()`s will have to be custom. I'll accept this answer in a week, if no one has a simpler suggestion until then

Comment: I can only say that it's worth it in our (quite big, 300k lines of kotlin) projects. But at this point i'm sure i'd do that for all new projects going forwards. It's good not to be bound to material artifact

Comment: And i thought our 28k was already pretty large...

Comment: Take into account that compose adds A LOOOOT of lines to that calculation. cloc cannot separate those, but i'm confident it's like 30-40% of all code